# How do I make the variable bold in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to make bold a string stored in a variable called boldtext. I want a simple one line code for this. I am not from coding background. Please help

**Edit 1:**
I made mistake in my original question. So, I am putting the question again.

My need = I want variable boldtext to be bold.

```
function calendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Course');
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername(); //gives user name
  var firstpart = user.split('.')[0]; //gives first part of user name
  var uppercase = firstpart.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstpart.substring(1);//makes first letter upper case
  var boldtext = 'Nice work, ' + uppercase //This has to be made bold
  var bold  = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
  var boldname = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(boldtext).setTextStyle(boldtext.indexOf(uppercase), boldtext.length, bold).build(); //mistake is here by me.
    spreadsheet.getRange('X53').setValue(boldname + 'Reminder is added to your calendar');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  var user  = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername();
  var first = user.split('.')[0];
  var name  = first[0].toUpperCase() + first.substring(1);
  var text  = 'Nice work, ' + name;
  var bold  = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(text).setTextStyle(text.indexOf(name), text.length, bold).build();

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setRichTextValue(value);
}
```

**Reference**

- [Class RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)

**Updated variant**

```
function calendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Course');
  var user        = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername();
  var firstpart   = user.split('.')[0];
  var name        = firstpart[0].toUpperCase() + firstpart.substring(1);
  var boldtext    = 'Nice work, ' + name;
  var bold        = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
  var text        = ' Reminder is added to your calendar';
  var value       = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(boldtext + text).setTextStyle(0, boldtext.length, bold).build();
  spreadsheet.getRange('X53').setRichTextValue(value);
}
```

Comment: Yuri, thanks for the help. I made mistake in my question. I have added my latest code in EDIT 1. I am again confused. Please please help. Can I get a simple one line code?

Comment: I've added the variant to make Bold another part of the text. And there is no way to make some variable 'Bold'. Bold style is a part of the RichTextObject. The object has some text (all text), and part of the text has some style properties (bold, ltalics, color, etc). Then you can put the object (a whole object) into a cell with the method `.setRichTextValue()`

Comment: Can you please help me for this question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71428113/how-do-i-get-to-show-my-name-as-sender-in-the-emails-send-from-app-script

Comment: Alas, I'm not an expert in GmailApp. Probably I can figure out a solution, but it will take time. I belive someone will provide the answer pretty soon.