# How do I get to show my name as sender in the emails send from app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

My code now looks like this:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, body, {htmlBody : body});
```

**My Reference Question:**
[Syntax Error for adding signature to email created from sheets using apps script for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71418610/syntax-error-for-adding-signature-to-email-created-from-sheets-using-apps-script?noredirect=1#comment126239650_71418610)

**My Issue:**
It shows sender as alex.ken@....

**What I want:** I want Scripts to take the name of the users. All users have set different names for their email address in Google Settings.

PS - Please note I have multiple users using the sheet/macro so I can't have fix value in the name parameter.

Please please help.

**Edit 1=Solution:**

```
var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUsername(); //gives username
var firstpart = user.split('.')[0]; //gives first part of username
var uppercase = firstpart.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstpart.substring(1); //makes first letter upper case
var display = uppercase + " with Ban Company";
.
.
.
.
GmailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, body, {htmlBody : body + signature,cc: "test@gmail.com",name:display});
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add a [mcve] showing how your script will read the values from the sheet and how will it select the specific value to be used when sending a specific email.

Comment: Solutions should be added as answers, not as part of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I will keep that in mind. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution will work for emails in the format `name.surname@...`, but if the user has something else like `itadmin@...`, a nickname, or any other email variant you may run into issues.

An alternative solution would be to use the [People API Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people) to retrieve the current user's Profile name, since Apps Script's `Session.getActiveUser()` only includes the user's email and there are some scenarios [where it won't work](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#detailed-documentation).

This includes more steps and they'll have to authorize the People API but you can get any user's profile name.

1. [Enable the Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) in the Apps Script editor by clicking the + next to `Services`. You can then add the People service.

[image: Adding a service]

2. [Add the profile scope to your project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes?authuser=0#setting_explicit_scopes) by editing the appscript.json manifest file.

```js
  {
    ...
    "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
    ],
   ...
  }
```

3. Add a function that will retrieve the current user's profile name information from the People API.

```js
//This will contain a user's names
function getCurrentUser(){
  var currentuser = People.People.get("people/me", {"personFields":"names"})
  return currentuser.names[0]
}

var firstname = getCurrentUser().givenName //gets the user's first name
var fullname = getCurrentUser().displayName // gets the user's full profile name

//You can then add either variable as the name 

GmailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, body, {htmlBody : body + signature,cc: "test@gmail.com",name:firstname});
```

In case you need it you can also retrieve much more than just the names, but also other user profile info. Check out the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person).

Comment: Omg, that was so detailed. Amazing solution! I learnt so much. Thank you for the efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
const name = 'Alex from Ban' // replace the string by someway to assign the value that you want to use. 
GmailApp.sendEmail(address, subject, body, {htmlBody : body, name: name });
```

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options

Comment: Ruben, thank you for the solution. But please note multiple users use the sheet so I can't have fix value in the name parameter. All users have set different names in the their Gmail settings. Pls help

Comment: @user18308583 Please edit the question to add a [mcve] showing how your script will read the values from the sheet and how will it select the specific value to be used when sending a specific email.

Comment: Ruben, your suggestion to come up with some variable for name parameter helped me. My name parameter is now set to a variable. Thanks a ton..